# Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom` for routing in my `React` application. Part of my app extracted in another package. List of dependencies looks like this:

**./app/dashboard/package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@app/components": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

**./app/components/package.json**

```
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I use components from `@app/components` which require components from `react-router-dom` I getting this errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router> 
The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>
```

Why throws this error? In `App.js` I use `BrowserRouter`

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Placeholder } from '@app/components';

const Auth = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './pages/Auth'));
const Index = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './pages/Index'));

const App = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<Placeholder />}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
      <Route path="/" component={Index} />
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
);

export default App;
```

**client.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: If anyone adds `<Router>` tags in an attempt to fix this, note that you must import `BrowserRouter as Router` for that to work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Trouble with 2 instance of React

Comment: Trying to render multiple instances of <BrowserRouter> caused this exception in my code, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @rodurico I am facing same issue. How did you resolve it?

Comment: @SawanPatodia I had to redraw the root component. You must have a single <Router> inside a single <BrowserRouter> in your entire project.

Answer (score 37):

I solved this problem by changing:

```
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router";
```

to

```
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
```

just add  -dom.

Comment: I had the same problem with Redirect being imported from "react-router"

Answer (score 33):

I had this problem whilst testing and solved it by wrapping my test component with Routers.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Header from '../components/Header/Header';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

it('renders Header without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');

  ReactDom.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
    </BrowserRouter>, 
  div);

  ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

> Jest, Enzyme: Invariant Violation: You should not use  or , To
> test a component (with Jest) that contains  and withRouter you
> need to import Router in you test, not in your component import {
> BrowserRouter as  Invariant Violation: You should not use  or
> withRouter() outside a  According to react router 4 docs, the
> components are considered valid, where I can create components
> composed of  s, then import them into another component and
> place inside a  .

Comment: Thanks. This one is just what I needed for testing.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `<MemoryRouter>` for the tests?

Answer (score 15):

I fixed that problem just importing the `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` in `index.js` and adding:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <App>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

within:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 10):

You should include Route tag, Link tag inside the Router tag.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>About</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
           <h1>W3Adda - Simple SPA</h1>
           <nav>
             <ul>
               <li>
                 <Link to="/">Home</Link>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <Link to="/about">About</Link>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <Link to="/contact">Users</Link>
               </li>
             </ul>
           </nav>

           <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
           <Route path="/about" component={About} />
           <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
         </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 8):

I got this during testing my component which linked to the project (using `npm link`) and because of that `react-router-dom` loaded more than once, following solution works in my case:

Inside `webpack.config.js` I added:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {        
        'react-router-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-router-dom')
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone comes here for the same problem with <Link> instead of <Route>, as I have, I needed to add both `react-router` and `react-router-dom` as aliases like this for it to work, even though I don't have `react-router` as a dependency.

Comment: 'Bless you!! This also happens when dealing with local packages that have `react-router-dom` as dependency

Answer (score 6):

You need import the named export `Router` as well from `react-router-dom` and wrap it around your Switch/Route components.

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<Placeholder />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
        <Route path="/" component={Index} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: I wrap all of my app in `client.jsx`

Comment: This solution worked for me too tho I'm kinda surprise. Just like OP I have that `Router` in my client code.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with Redirect component. It turned out that I called Redirect from 'react-router' instead of 'react-router-dom'.

> ```
> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation with the main app created with CRA and components library. We have two instances of `react-router-dom` working independently. Component from library uses `<Link>` while parent app has `<Router>`.

Inspired by @Pavel answer I discovered that issue can be solved by adding aliases. If you are using webpack, you can change the way it will resolve the `react-router-dom` module. You can overwrite the default order in which webpack will look for your dependencies and make your parent application node_modules more prioritized than component node module resolution order:

aliases.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const directory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = (relativePath) => path.resolve(directory, relativePath);

module.exports = {
  react: resolveApp('node_modules/react'),
  'react-router-dom': resolveApp('node_modules/react-router-dom'),
};
```

that are used by config-override.js to override default CRA settings:

```
const { addWebpackAlias, override, removeModuleScopePlugin } = require('customize-cra');
const aliases = require('./aliases');

module.exports = override(removeModuleScopePlugin(), addWebpackAlias(aliases));
```

or for webpack.config.js (if it's not CRA):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    "react-router-dom": path.resolve(appFolder, "node_modules", "react-router-dom"),
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my Create React App when running tests and I solved it by placing `<Router></Router` inside `App.js` instead of in `Index.js` as I have always done.

Before:

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Route path="/blabla" component={Whatever}
    </div>
)
```

After:

Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
            <Header />
            <Route path="/blabla" component={Whatever}
        </Router>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this cryptic error by deleting the dependency of 'react-router-dom' from MyComponent. I deleted 'node_modules/react-router-dom' and from 'package.json'
My App is structured as follows:

```
    AppFolder
    ├── README.md
    ├── build
    ├── node_modules
    │   ├── react-router-dom
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    │   ├── favicon.ico
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── manifest.json
    └── src
        ├── App.css
        ├── App.js
        ├── App.test.js
        ├── index.js
        ├── redux
        │   ├── reducers.js
        │   └── store.js
        └── serviceWorker.js


    MyComponent
    ├── README.md
    ├── dist
    ├── node_modules
    │   ├── react-router-dom
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── rollup.config.js
    └── src
        ├── index.js
        ├── styles.css
        └── test.js
```

This is the source code for App.js

```
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent'

export default App(){
 return (
 <div className="App">
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <header className="App-header">

        </header>
        <Route path="/home" component={MyComponent}/>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  </div>)
}
```

This is the export for MyComponent

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

If 'react-router-dom' is left in the component folder, then the error appears.

Comment: The issue for me was that I had installed both `react-router-dom` and `react-router`. I removed the latter and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error, by wrapping my parent component inside Router.

Before solving error

```
<Header />
<div className="col-md-12 pd-0-0">
  <div className="row">
    <Sidebar />
    <div className="col-sm-10 col-md-10 pd-0-0" style={style}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard/check-in" component={CheckIn} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/deals" component={Deals} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/events" component={Events} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/invoice" component={Invoice} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/notification" component={Notification} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/redemption" component={Redemptions} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/restriction-management" component={RestrictionManagement} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After solving error

```
<Router>
  <Header />
  <div className="col-md-12 pd-0-0">
    <div className="row">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="col-sm-10 col-md-10 pd-0-0" style={style}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard/check-in" component={CheckIn} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/deals" component={Deals} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/events" component={Events} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/invoice" component={Invoice} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/notification" component={Notification} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/redemption" component={Redemptions} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/restriction-management" component={RestrictionManagement} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue was in your root component where you are doing routing, you should not add any component outside of `Router` tag in the component, that component only expect single/multiple component wraped by `Route` under `Router` in that components.

wrong code (but it will run, but you are creating bug) -

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I only remove `<Header/>` , it solved the issue.

write code -

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just change "react-router" on "react-router-dom"

```
import {Route} from "react-router";
```

to

```
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GatsbyJS and getting this error just change your

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was caused due to mixing up usage of things (withRouter, MemoryRouter) from react-router and react-router-dom. By using only things from react-router-dom, the invariant error vanished. Hope this helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<Link>` tag in a component that doesn't have the  imported could give this error, try importing the `BrowserRouter` from `'react-router-dom'`

```
import {BrowserRouter , Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

then make sure to wrap your linked tags in the  tag

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by removing `<BrowserRouter>` from `router.js` and including it in `app.js`

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/book" component={Book} />
      <Route path="/client" component={Client} />
      <Route path="/rent" component={Rent} />
      <Route path="/dash" component={Dash} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Header></Header>
       <Routes/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Router**  outside of your components. Wrap all components inside the **Router** then will able to use **Link** in your components.

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

```
<Router>
        <Appbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/mac" exact component={Mac} />
        </Switch>
       <Footer />
      </Router>
```

Comment: Am not sure it is a good practice to wrap the router all around like that

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by importing

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and wrapped all the `Route` components under the `Router` component

```
 <Router>
     <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
 </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to replace Rails views in a Solidus app.

The solution for me was to edit the vies to use the React Router that I had just added, but apparently hadn't fully configured.

For example, I edited `views/spree/home/index.html` from:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= react_component("Home/Index") %>
```

to:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= react_component("Routes") %>
```

For more reference, here is my `javascript/components/Route.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home/Index";
import Product from "./Products/Show";

class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/products/:slug" component={Product} />
      </Router>
    );
  };
};

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while I wrape App component with withRouter

**Error:**

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Placeholder } from '@app/components';

const Auth = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './pages/Auth'));
const Index = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './pages/Index'));

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Suspense fallback={<Placeholder />}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
      <Route path="/" component={Index} />
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default withRouter(App);
```

**Solution:**

we already using Switch component, after that I have removed withRouter

```
    import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
    import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Placeholder } from '@app/components';
    
    const Auth = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './pages/Auth'));
    const Index = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './pages/Index'));
    
    const App = () => (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<Placeholder />}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
          <Route path="/" component={Index} />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem while unit testing here is something that worked out for me:

```
function mountComponentWithRouter(Component, props) {
  const Teste = withRouter(prop => <Component {...prop} {...props} />);

  return mount(
    <HashRouter>
      <Teste />
    </HashRouter>,
    {
      context: { router },
      childContextTypes: { router: PropTypes.object.isRequired }
    }
  );
}
```

With this any react-router-dom component inside `Component` will have all of those props (pathname, hash, state, search) that are usually passed down naturally when running the application.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer is right inside official doc from reactstrap for Navbar, see this website https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

They guided that we need to use this import

```
import {NavLink} from 'reactstrap';
```

Answer (score -12):

You have a hanging comma at the end of the render call after `document.getElementById('root')`.

```
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: Not a problem. JS allows that.