# How do I use React's Link component in an external npm package without error: invariant "you should not use link outside router"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I've created an NPM package that renders an icon menu (which will be used in various projects). The user is allowed to send a 'route' prop to that icon menu. Thus, each icon can be a link to a different page.

However, I keep getting the following error when I'm importing my package:

> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`

Even though I import and render my icon menu inside a router of my project. Or, in this case, a BrowserRouter.

Because it's a huge project, I've quickly recreated the process in two parts.
Remember, the package is an NPM package. If it was a component inside my project this wouldn't have been a problem. However, I need this package in different, identical projects.

### Part 1: The NPM package

**IconMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from '@IDB/react-iconlibrary';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const IconMenu = ({ items }) => {
    return (
        <div className='icon_menu'>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <Link to={item.route}>
                    <Icon className='icon_box_icon' key={index} name={item.icon} title={item.name} />
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
export default IconMenu
```

### Part 2: The project

**Project.js**

```
import { IconMenu } from '@IDB/ui-elements';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Project extends Component  {
    render () {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div id='page'>
                    <Route path='/' render={(props) => (
                        <IconMenu 
                            items={[
                                {
                                    icon: 'Edit',
                                    name: 'Edit page',
                                    route: '/edit'
                                },
                                {
                                    icon: 'View',
                                    name: 'View page',
                                    route: '/save'
                                }
                            ]}
                        />
                        )} 
                    />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `withRouter` for IconMenu component like this - `export default withRouter(IconMenu);`

Comment: I've just tried it, but it still returns an error. Although it now says: 
> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(IconMenu) /> outside a <Router>

Comment: Other possible reasons of this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552147/invariant-failed-you-should-not-use-route-outside-a-router

Comment: Thank you for this information. I have just tried something, which could be a "solution", I will post it in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765645/how-to-fix-react-router-dom-context-conflict-when-using-npm-link) and was able to solve it using the following approach.

But first, **why are we hitting this edge case?**

This error is thrown when two instances of `react-router-dom` are present and [conflict](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6789#issuecomment-502490351) with each other.

In my use case, this happened when I used `npm link` to "install" a npm package I am developing to abstract `Link`.

I believe in the use case described in this question, perhaps `react-router-dom` was installed as a dependency when it should likely have been installed as a [peer dependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) (to mitigate conflicts).

Here is an excerpt of my `package.json`.

```json
{
  "name": "react-hashlink",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "npm-check-updates": "^10.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

## Solution inspired by React [docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react)

> one possible fix is to run `npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react` from `mylib`. This should make the library use the application’s React copy.

I created two helper scripts to link and unlink peer dependencies from host projects.

### .env

```sh
PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH=/Users/sunknudsen/Code/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/node_modules
```

### link-peer-deps.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f .env ]
then
  export $(cat .env | sed 's/#.*//g' | xargs)
fi

npm link \
  $PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH/react \
  $PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH/react-dom \
  $PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH/react-router-dom
```

### unlink-peer-deps.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

npm unlink react react-dom react-router-dom
```

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Great finding  @sunknudsen! Thanks for sharing. I indeed hope this issue could help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

This is just avoiding the issue. See [Sunknudsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773452/10133180) for an actual solution

### Start original answer

So, this is not the best solution and does avoid the problem, but this is how I fixed  it.

### Part 1: The NPM package

**IconMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from '@IDB/react-iconlibrary';

const IconMenu = ({ items }) => {
    return (
        <div className='icon_menu'>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                item.render(<Icon className='icon_box_icon' key={index} name={item.icon} title={item.name} />)
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
export default IconMenu
```

### Part 2: The project

**Project.js**

```
import { IconMenu } from '@IDB/ui-elements';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Project extends Component  {
    render () {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div id='page'>
                    <Route path='/' render={(props) => (
                        <IconMenu 
                            items={[
                                {
                                    icon: 'Edit',
                                    name: 'Edit page',
                                    render: (item) => <Link to='/test'>{item}</Link>
                                },
                                {
                                    icon: 'View',
                                    name: 'View page',
                                    render: (item) => <Link to='/test'>{item}</Link>
                                }
                            ]}
                        />
                        )} 
                    />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Cédric. Did you manage to include Link in your package finally?

Comment: @sunknudsen Not really; but I also stepped over to a different project where we use Next.js's static pages for routing. So the above issue won't be relevant anymore. However, I don't see my solution as "final". If someone else has a better solution that allows the usage of Link in an external package, that would be awesome.

Comment: Hey Cédric, after way to many hours of debugging, I believe I found the issue. See answer bellow.