# Why is withRouter used with connect () breaking my react app?

Tags: reactjs, router

Good evening everyone,

I have been trying to add withRouter to my react app so it does not break because of the connect function (see code below).

My code is working, but when i add withRouter to the line below, it breaks my app with the following message :

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

**Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Connect(App)) /> outside a Router>**

i found this topic : [Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552147/invariant-failed-you-should-not-use-route-outside-a-router) but it's not helping me with me issue when i try to replace with a single Router

Please find below the whole code used :

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect}from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from './store/actions/index'

// Composants
import Layout from './components/hoc/Layout/Layout'
import BudgetHandler from './components/BudgetHandler/BudgetHandler'
import DashBoard from './components/DashBoard/DashBoard'
import Movements from './components/Movements/Movements'
import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import Logout from './components/Logout/Logout'

import classes from './App.module.css'

const App = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.onTryAutoSignup()
  },[])

  let routes = <React.Fragment>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
    </React.Fragment>

  if(props.isAuthentificated) {
    routes = <React.Fragment>
        <Route path="/movements" component={Movements} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="/handler" component={BudgetHandler} />
        <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
    </React.Fragment>
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.App}>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
        {routes}
      </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthentificated: state.auth.token !== null
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState())
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

And this is happening because i am trying to add this function to the useEffect hook to check permanently if the user is auth or not :

in actions/auth.js

```
export const authCheckState = () => {
    return dispatch => {
         const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
         if(!token) {
             dispatch(logout())
         } else {
             const expirationTime = new Date(localStorage.getItem('expirationDate'))
             const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId')
             if(expirationTime > new Date()){
                 dispatch(logout())
             } else {
                dispatch(finalSignIn(token, userId))
                dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(expirationTime.getSeconds() - new Date().getSeconds()))
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Have a good evening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

withRouter can only be used in children components of  element. In your case can be used with Movements, DashBoard and other childrens. use it while exporting Movements like

```
export default withRouter(Movements)
```

on Movements page.