# Error in ReactDOM Render when use Route from react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, react-dom

When I try to use the Route coming from 'react-router-dom' I get this error on the screen.

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from thenfile it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Router.Consumer`.

```
  3 | import App from './App';
  4 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(
  7 |   <React.StrictMode>
  8 |     <App />
  9 |   </React.StrictMode>,
```

My code from index.js is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And my App.js is

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import FooterTR from './components/Footer';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages';
import About from './pages/about';    
import Blog from './pages/blog';
import ContactUs from './pages/contactUs';
import SignUp from './pages/signUp';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
        <Route path='/contact-us' component={ContactUs} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
      </Switch>

      <FooterTR />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure its because of `Route` ? It could be due to one the components you render in each `Route`. Make sure you have exported `Home`,`About`,`Blog`,`ContactUs` and `SignUp` as a default export from the respective files.

Comment: Hey! I managed to fix it, the problem was in the app.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an issue with you components(`Navbar, FooterTR, Home, About, Blog, ContactUs, SignUp`) import statement. But if all those things are perfect then,
Try to write your `App.js` like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import FooterTR from './components/Footer';
import Home from './pages';
import About from './pages/about';    
import Blog from './pages/blog';
import ContactUs from './pages/contactUs';
import SignUp from './pages/signUp';

function App() {
  return (
   <>
   <Navbar />
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
        <Route path='/contact-us' component={ContactUs} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    <FooterTR />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @Stéphani Pinheiro Ferreira Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, but now I got another different error. I'm analyzing it.

Comment: He says " Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router> "

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552147/invariant-failed-you-should-not-use-route-outside-a-router
Does this resolve your error `Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router>` ?

Comment: Yes. I am solving the error according to this topic.