# Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> The whole page is white

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link,Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='p-5 pb-0 flex flex-wrap sm:justify-between justify-center item-center border-b dark:border-gray-700 border-gray-200'>
        <div className="w-screen flex justify-between items-center space-x-5">

          <Link to="/">
         
            <p className='text-2xl '>Not Google</p>
          </Link>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552147/invariant-failed-you-should-not-use-route-outside-a-router)

Answer (score 0):

Your Navbar component should be a child (any nesting depth) of Router component. Please check where is your Router component (BrowserRouter, etc...)

Comment: Can you please elaborate with example code,?